# Regex to remove quotes around attributes when possible

Tags: php, html, regex

I search a regex, working with PHP, to clean (and minify) my HTML code.

Here's an example of an HTML tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
```

And the excepted result :

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
```

Another example :

```
<img src="picture.png" alt="Picture" width="800" height="20"/>
```

And the excepted result :

```
<img src="picture.png" alt=Picture width=800 height=20/>
```

I already use this class : https://github.com/mrclay/minify/blob/master/lib/Minify/HTML.php 
But the feature I want is missing.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

`"([^"=.]+?)"`

And replace by `$1`.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/oG9mZ4/1)

Basically, it means:

```
"                # start quote character
(                # start group
    [^"=.]+?     # if the content between these quotes contains 
                     # equal or dot characters.. then don't match
)                # end group
"                # end quote character
```